# Apple Developer Program enrolling with a p.iva and the company name

Tags: registration, apple

i am italian, i got a D-U-N-S number for my individual company (partita iva for those who know what it is).

Now Apple is asking me to enroll as an individual cause the D-U-N-S number is attributed to an individual physic person, why i can't enroll as company since for the italian law i am a company?

Also why i must enroll as an individual since my company can accept payments by the law, what i lose as legal entity enrolling for an individual account?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This probably is not the best place to ask this question as it's not related with Webmasters, but as I know the answer, here it goes.

You don't have a company, you are a solo / individual entrepreneur that can behave like a company in terms of accepting payments after issuing invoices. Your VAT number or D-U-N-S as you say identify you and your ability to to commercial trading as a person / professional / entrepreneur.

A company, on the other hand has it's VAT number as a collective institution and therefore its number is different, that's why Apple is saying you should enroll as individual, because your numbers shows exactly that.

Just because you both pay VAT (or partitia IVA as you say) doesn't mean you are the same type of commercial actor. There's a difference between both concepts and Apple is right in this case and you'll lose nothing.

Comment: thank you! what i mean is why i should look as an individual togheter with non-companies in the store, this makes me freaky out, cause i am not a kid who is enrolling the program just for fun... anyway i guess there is nothing we can do about it pff